# Choix entre l'article et l'adjectif démonstratif

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

Si je voulais raconter ce qui m’est arrivé un certain jour et si je commençais par le début, est-ce que je dirais :

> Le matin, je me suis réveillée à sept heures comme d’habitude.

ou bien :

> Ce matin, je me suis réveillée à sept heures comme d’habitude.

Y a-t-il une différence ?

Comment: « 7 » a été changé en « sept » comme en français les chiffres ne s'écrivent pas toujours en chiffres arabes :   http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5135

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les deux conviennent également. Tout dépend de la situation du narrateur dans le récit.

Le matin -> Le narrateur se situe un autre jour que le jour du matin en question

Ce matin -> Le narrateur se situe le jour du matin en question. Ce matin = Le matin de ce jour.

Comment: C'est parfaitement clair, merci beaucoup !

Answer (score -1):

Lorsque l'article « le » dans  « le matin » est compris comme ayant une fonction déterminative, alors la première phrase convient;

> Le matin (de ce jour-là) je me suis réveillé à sept heures comme d'habitude.

Il ne faut pas confondre l'article « le » avec sa fonction générique dans ce cas-ci.

La seconde phrase ne convient pas, il faut quelque chose de plus et c'est l'adverbe « là ». la définition du TLFi supporte cela :

> (TLFi) **ce** : [Dans l'espace de temps actuellement vécu par le locuteur et précisé par le subst.] Ce matin, cet après-midi, ce soir, cette année; en ce moment; à compter de ce jour
>   (TLFi) **actuellement** : I. Lang cour. Dans les circonstances actuelles, au moment même où l'on parle, où l'on agit

En anglais « **ce matin-là** » se traduit par « **[that](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/that%20morning/forced) morning** » (vérifier le bas de cette page web) whereas « **ce matin** » se traduit pas « **[this](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/this%20morning) morning** ».

> **Ce** matin-**là**, je me suis réveillé à sept heures comme d'habitude.

Si le matin dont il est question est celui de la veille ou de l'avant-veille du jour de l'énonciation alors il est possible qu'employer une autre construction soit plus utile; voici cette construction;

> Hier matin, je me suis réveillé à sept heures comme d'habitude.
>   Avant-hier matin, je me suis réveillé à sept heures comme d'habitude.

Lorsque vous dites

« Le matin, je me suis réveillée à 7 heures comme d’habitude. » vous parlez d'un réveil  sur une période de temps, tous les matins de cette période donnée, votre réveil ayant été fait à sept heures ; la période peut ne consister que d'un seul jour.

Lorsque vous dites « Ce matin, je me suis réveillée à 7 heures comme d’habitude. » vous ne pouvez pas parler d'un autre matin que celui du jours au cours duquel vous vous exprimez.

**Quelques notions supplémentaires**

Lorsque vous dites « **Ce matin j'ai fais un grand travail. » l'interlocuteur comprend toujours que vous parlez de ce matin qui correspond au jours durant lequel vous exprimez ce fait (que vous avez fait un grand travail). Si vous dites le 15 décembre la même chose en parlant du 10 novembre vous avez deux possibilités ;

- 1/ dans la conversation, ce matin particulier n'a pas été introduit ; alors vous devez le spécifier et il n'est pas question d'utiliser « ce » (pas du tout) ; vous dites donc quelque chose comme « Le matin du 10 novembre …» ;
- 2/ le matin en question vient d'être mentionné dans la conversation ; dans ce cas il faut utiliser « ce » mais pas tout seul, cela de façon à différencier le matin de celui du jours durant lequel vous parlez; vous dites donc "**Ce matin-là j'ai fais … **»; cependant rien ne vous empêche d'être plus précis et vous pouvez aussi dire, mais maintenant sans utiliser « là » en raison d'un complément de nom que vous ajoutez, « **Ce matin du 10 novembre j'ai … **».

**Il ne faut pas confondre « ce matin » en tant que complément circonstanciel de temps et « ce matin » en tant que COD.**

> Il y a cinquante ans de cela ; c'était alors le 10 décembre 1968 au matin ; **ce matin** je ne l'oublierai pas, il y avait un mètre de neige devant la porte, nous étions bloqués à l'intérieur.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas. Qu'est-ce que vous voulez dire par : "vous ne pouvez pas parler d'un autre matin que celui du jours au cours duquel vous vous exprimez" ? Je parle d'un certain matin, par exemple du 10 novembre 2018....